# Azure WebApp not able to communicate with Azure WebSql Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

The Scenario:

A webApp (Not WebSite nor WebService) on Azure using WebAPI fails to connect to its Azure Database. There is no WebApp IP to open in the database firewall although I have opened (temporarily) 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 which did not help.
We receive the following generic error message:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"

Running the Web App locally it connects to the Azure database fine.

The WebApp connects to the database through EF6.

So we know the connection string works, we know the database is accessible and the WebAPI works ... it only fails when the WebApp is placed on Azure.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Have you verified that the connection string you see in the App Settings blade of the portal matches that of the connection string you're using locally? That would be my first bet.

Comment: Connection settings are correct - we checked.

Comment: It's not likely anything to do with the Web App itself. It's likely to be a config issue. It could be useful to log the connection string, where you pass it to EF, to verify that the code is getting the right connection string from App Settings. Further, you can remote debug via Visual Studio. It will probably take some debugging on your part, it's a fairly generic error you're getting. :(

Comment: It is definitely a configuration error: But I think it is the WebSql server config that is the problem. Which is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: You can access a DebugConsole at {sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole. Go there and try to ping your server name. You can also check the environment variables for your connection string and verify it shows up correctly there as well. Given that this might require some back and forth with us MSFT folks, you might want to ask this question on MSDN. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: What response error you get from the server ? 404 / 500

Also you should be aware of the retry policy in Azure SQL See this article http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is a little more complex than it needs to be. You can't get a webApp to communicate with a WebSql database without serious fudging. However, the correct although more costly solution is this:

1. Create a Ms SQL Database VM.
2. Create a Ms Windows VM for the API
3. Create a vNetwork and place both VMs on the network
4. Configure the API to use the internal IP of the network that belongs to the
   Database VM

Voila.

Comment: upon publishing you can generate a new sql db for a web app. Is that not an option for you?

Comment: We tried that but could not get our API to connect with the WebSql database.